# Getting errrors while trying to import pyautogui with python3

Tags: python

```enter code here`So I installed`pyautogui` but I had a problem importing it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from objc._bridgesupport import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import email.parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
```

ok i tried to install `pyobjc-core` and `pyobjc` but I got the same problem again, and I also do not understand why there is a reference to the email package```

```css
body
{
background-color:gray;
}
```

Comment: "i tried to install" - _how_ did you try to install these? Did the installation succeed? If not, please post the full error message you got.

Comment: This link might help https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Did you install it via pip, for example, running ```pip install pyautogui``` from an admin CMD?

Comment: @ForceBru i used pip and no error occurred before but after importing it in my python code i get that error.

Comment: @JoeA i tried but i got the same error.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon  yes.

Comment: Just curious do you have a file named email.py in you're directory which you are working in?

Comment: So I just installed it via pip and it has ```pymsgbox, PyTweening, pyscreeze, pyrect, pygetwindow``` as dependencies only (no email etc.) Do you have a file called pyautogui/email?

Comment: @Joa A  yes i have a file named email.py. For now i'm not working on it.

Comment: ok i rename the file and i could import pyautogui without errorr. thank you to all of you for helping me.

Comment: @Aryan Sood happy to help!